# MySql skips first record found

Tags: mysql

in my database i have 10 records with almost exact same data , they differ only by one field ( the field is not in the query) and when i run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id= 'MyUserName' AND follow_back = 0 AND until_date= '2009-10-13'  LIMIT 12
```

it shows only 9 records , any one stumbled upon similar problem ? 
Thanks & waiting for your answers !

Comment: Please post the results you are expecting to see and the results you are actually seeing.

Comment: You might want to try this query with `LIMIT 0, 12` instead of `LIMIT 12` and tell us if this makes a difference.

Comment: @Dreamon Ahh, thanks. Wasn't sure about that.

Comment: wouldn't that show form 0 to 12 , my idea is to display 12 records only , no matter what number are they

Comment: @Aviatrix no, it's actually equal to `LIMIT 12` as you can see in the MySQL Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is there's nothing wrong with your query, so

```
user_id!='MyUserName'
```

or

```
follow_back != 0
```

or

```
until_date != '2009-10-13'
```

Try just querying on one criterion at a time and see if you can norrow it down. Perhaps `follow_back` is NULL?

Comment: ugh , yes , you are right , one of the records was NULL i didn't saw it thanks !

Answer (score 1):

When trying to debug problems like these, what I would usually do is to try solving it using a divide and conquer approach.

So try and remove one where condition at a time, then execute the query.  That way you will be able to isolate the offending condition.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that all values in column user_id are the same? Maybe that one missing record has user_id = 'MyUserName ' (note the space).

Comment: Yes im sure cuz they are auto added :)

Comment: I believe that MySQL automatically trims spaces from strings. SELECT 'test' = 'test ' returns 1.

Comment: @Ian: And you're right: if the column is a CHAR or VARCHAR data type, trailing space doesn't matter. See also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a minute ago. It turned out it wasn't the query that was the problem, but the IF where I check if anything's returned. Might want to check that.